# choosing motherboard and 1U server case

Tags: motherboard, server, case

I've got my eyes set on the Ryzen 5 1600x cpu. I'd like to install it in 19' rack, using 1U space.

What chassis and mother board do you recommend? Will I need to purchase a separate cooler? I wont be installing GPU, and 220W PSU is probably all I need. Budget is $500, but cheeper is preferred.

Comment: 1U is way thin. You'd struggle to get a decent HSF in there. You ought to look at 2U PC cases and go from there.

Comment: Even though I will be using only a 200W PSU?